# Why does my svgs always take the same size of memory?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, google-chrome-devtools

Heyho,

yesterday I just recognized it doesnt matter how complex a svg is they always take around 2 MB memory in the Chrome dev tools (thats the sizes of the profile snaptshots). I tested a really **small svg** with **4 paths** and it takes **2.6 MB** in every profile snapshot. And I also tested a svg with **26.981 paths** and its profile snapshot always takes **2.2 MB**. But the file sizes are massively different. The **small svg has 3KB and the large svg 7.4 MB**.

Can anyone explain me this logic, please? Does the memory size become significantly different when I would animate both svgs?

Comment: One suggestion might be to use a memory profiler.

Comment: Isnt the memory tab in chrome dev tools a memory profiler?I take a profile snapshot and it tells me how much memory the css, html, svg, js, etc. takes. Or not?

Comment: Well sure, can you show the complete profile snapshot maybe? Does this do a deep memory profiling? I remember Chromium at least had such a tool (in the past). Also I'm just shooting in the dark. :)

Comment: Devtools heap snapshot is primarily targeted at measuring JS memory so it probably doesn't measure the **internal** browser structures for DOM/SVG. Those can be only reliably measured by using the [internal memory profiler](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/memory/debugging_memory_issues.md).